# Starting Jest in Watch mode error and missing Debug link in Visual Studio Code

Tags: unit-testing, debugging, visual-studio-code, jestjs

I have 2 Jest issues:

1) I'm using VS Code and Jest to debug my unit tests. For some reason, the Debug link has disappeared, making debugging of individual tests more difficult:

[image: Missing debug link]

2) Jest no longer watches my tests:

```
Starting Jest in Watch mode failed too many times and has been stopped.
```

[image: Error Starting Jest in Watch mode failed too many times and has been stopped.]

Things I tried:

- Using the Help link. This leads to Jest's troubleshooting page, but does not say how to set a watch.
- Editing my Jest extension settings. Not sure that any of these would set a watch.
- Comparing my launch.json to that of my teammate.
- Uninstalling and reinstalling the Jest extension from VS Code.
- Disabling and reenabling the Jest extension.
- `npm install`
- Restarting my machine.
- `jest --watch`

**How do I recover that Debug link over my unit tests and set a watch?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I recover that Debug link over my unit tests and set a watch?

1) 
The better solution was to delete the `@jest` directory from `C:\<project name>\<directory>\<directory>\node_modules` via File Explorer, and then reinstall Jest. This restored a missing `jest` file in `C:\<project anme>\<directory>\<directory>\node_modules\.bin` without adding lots of things I didn't need.

[image: Missing jest file]

2) This command,

```
npm install jest-cli
```

installed a missing `jest` file in `C:\<project name>\<directory>\<directory>\node_modules\.bin`

Caveat: I now have lots of extra things in my `package.json` and `package-lock.json` that I don't need and will have to remove before committing. I can remove these extra items by discarding the changes in VS Code or `git checkout master package.json`, but that also removes the `jest` file.

Comment: what about `npm i jest-cli —dev`?

Comment: @OlliD-Metz *what about `npm i jest-cli —dev?`* This command also works, and it also installs extra items, but thanks for the suggestion! It also says `Usage of the --dev option is deprecated. Use --only=dev instead.`